# fixed background image style not work with owl.carousel.js 2 slider

Tags: jquery, css, slider, owl-carousel

I'm trying to set the slider item's image as a background image with `background-attachment: fixed;` but this not works with the slider plugin "Owl.carousel2" it show white background.

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    margin:10,
    nav:true,
    items:1
})
```

```css
.owl-carousel .item {
  height:600px;
}
.owl-carousel .item .item-content {
  height:600px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed; /* not work !*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>



<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <div style="background-image:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg)" class="item-content">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Caption Title!</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div style="background-image:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg)" class="item-content">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Caption Title!</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div style="background-image:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg)" class="item-content">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Caption Title!</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

check the example here on [codepen](https://codepen.io/fayekramzy/pen/Gvdrrb)

Answer (score 0):

First step
Create your style sheet and call it any name like app css.
Then
In app.css write this

```
. item-content{    
    height:600px; 
    background-image:url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg);  
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover; 
    background-position: center; 
    background-attachment: fixed;     
}
```

This will be easier and will overwrite the current style

Comment: So what is the case, why you think your solution works? I tried it and nothing changed.

Comment: background-image:url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg'); 

Change that line.. I forgot to put single quotation

Answer (score -1):

please correct the syntax of inline style.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/i_am_maulik/pen/ayGpgP)

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme" style="background-image:url('https://amazingslider.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/dandelion.jpg')">
```

Answer (score -2):

First step
Create your style sheet and call it any name like app css.
Then
In app.css write this

```
. item-content{
     height:600px; 
     background-image:url('https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/82/contrail.jpg');
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     background-size:cover; 
     background-position: center; 
     background-attachment: fixed; 
}
```